# How to find the eigenvalues of $A+I$ given the eigenvalues of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Say the $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ has eigenvalues $a$, $b$ and $c$. Given $I$ is the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix, how to find the eigenvalues of $A+I$?

I think it could be $a+1$, $b+1$ and $c+1$ but I don't have any basis at all. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ AV=\lambda V \implies (A+I)V= \lambda V +V = (\lambda +1)V$$

Thus $\lambda +1$ does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:
$$
\det(\lambda I-A)=\det[(\lambda+1)I-(A+I)]
$$

Answer (score 2):

The eigenvalues of $A + I$ are indeed $a+ 1$, $b + 1$, $c + 1$; this follows from the following

***Fact:***

$A \vec v = \mu \vec v \Longleftrightarrow (A + \alpha I) \vec v = (\mu + \alpha ) \vec v; \tag 2$

***Proof of Fact:***

if

$A\vec v = \mu \vec v, \tag 3$

then

$(A + \alpha I)\vec v = A \vec v + \alpha I \vec v = \mu \vec v + \alpha \vec v = (\mu + \alpha) \vec v; \tag 4$

furthermore, if

$(A + \alpha I)\vec v = (\mu + \alpha) \vec v, \tag 5$

then

$A \vec v + \alpha \vec v = A \vec v + \alpha I\vec v = (A + \alpha I)\vec v = (\mu + \alpha) \vec v = \mu \vec v+ \alpha\vec v , \tag 5$

whence,

$A\vec v = \mu \vec v. \tag 6$

***End:  Proof of Fact.***

We now simply apply this ***Fact*** to the problem at hand to see the our opening affirmation holds.  Furthermore, the proof of our little ***Fact*** also shows that the eigenvectors corresponding to $a$, $b$, $c$ are those associated with $a + 1$, $b + 1$, $c + 1$, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, a much stronger statement is true. Namely, if $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of the $n\times n$ matrix $A$, then for any polynomial $p$ the eigenvalues of $p(A)$ are $p(\lambda_1),\ldots,p(\lambda_n)$.

Easiest way to see it is probably via the Jordan form, but there are several other arguments.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed $a+1$, $b+1$ and $c+1$, and the basis you have for $A$ works for $A+I$. Make sure you can see for yourself why this is.